# confusing about customize listview in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

What's the problem that my db is null? 
there says `Cursor cursor = myDb.getData(select * from Donation_Details); myDb : null` and it pops out the error below.

[image: myDb:Null]

And here is the runtime error says

[image: Runtime Error]

Here is the `DatabaseHelper` which When I assign & declear database.

```
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "eBossCharity.db";
    private static  final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public dbOpenHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

Here is the `dbAccess` when I want to get data from database.

```
public dbOpenHelper openHelper;
    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static dbAccess instance;

    public dbAccess(Context context) {
        this.openHelper = new dbOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public static dbAccess getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new dbAccess(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Cursor getData(String sql) {
        db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery("", null);
    }
```

Here is the `Summary page` when I want to show the data into the customize list view. I put a break point at line 13 and debug it. It says my database is null. I Called the `dbAccess` method `getData` and grab the database"Donation_details". It should show the data...

```
ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Model> mList;
    RecordListAdapter mAdapter = null;
    dbAccess myDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_summary__page);

        this.listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new RecordListAdapter(this,R.layout.row,mList);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getData("Select * from Donation_Details");
        mList.clear();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String txnno = cursor.getString(1);
            String name = cursor.getString(2);
            String txndate = cursor.getString(3);
            BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.valueOf(cursor.getDouble(4));
            String description1 = cursor.getString(5);
            String createddate = cursor.getString(7);

            mList.add(new Model(id,txnno,name,txndate,amount,description1,createddate));
        }
```

I think I missed something here and there. But I couldn't find it, Or maybe I typed wrong something to cause database is null? Can I have some guidance?  Thank in advance...

Comment: Before using a variable you should check for null like if(myDb == null) myDb = new dbAccess(context); then use the methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Write this

```
myDb = new dbAccess(this);
```

In your onCreate () after the line `setContentView(...)`

Try it..

Comment: I added this code at the Summary page which I want to Run the listview page. It doesn't work...

Comment: This code is for making null pointer exception go away, now what is the new error that you are getting?

Comment: Cannot find local variable 'cause'. Like the picture"Runtime error says".

Comment: Now, it's not showing nullpointer exception in getData() right?

Comment: Yes. It works, And I put try & catch when I run the `Cursor moveToNext`. It will go to Exception

Comment: Ok cool, but I cannot find the word "cause" in your code of Summary page.. Could you update the question with entire Summary page code, so that I can solve your other problem too..

Comment: I also couldn't find out the word "cause" at my every page... Don't know where is it.... @

Comment: Well then I guess this should be the accepted answer as one of your question was solved by this solution.

Comment: it says "cannot resolve symbol 'cause'" Where is this cause, can't seem to find it anywhere, or else we could have done it

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize 'dbAccess myDb'

Comment: Ya. I put `myDb = new dbAccess(this);` In my Oncreate.